# How to add a shortcut to my VsCode extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created an extension with VsCode but I want to start my extension without typing the command in the command bar (CTRL + SHIFT + P). I dont know how to achieve this.

Something like this:

[image]

If we click on `Ponicode: Unit Test`, it starts the command directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are searching about is `CodeLens`.

**Documentation**

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#codelens-show-actionable-context-information-within-source-code

**Sample**

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/codelens-sample

**Extensions using CodeLens**

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup